# How big can an answer be?

Tags: discussion

I have an answer to [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69/golf-you-a-quine-for-great-good) question that is quite long.  It is the best I can do and no one else has answered the question in the language (I am using Brain-Flak).

However my answer is very large (7e618).  It would require more bytes than there exists atoms in the observable universe to store the answer uncompressed.  I cannot include the answer for obvious reasons but I can include a very simple way to generate it given enough time and computational power.

Is there any policy on the upper limit of answer sizes?  Should there be?

Comment: The technical answer is that answers can be up to 30k characters. If you can describe a way to generate over 30k characters, or link to them then that is fine. However there's another issue. How can you be confident that a program that large (and untestable) meets the requirements of the challenge? It's not that I doubt you, it's just that `7e618` is an *astonishingly* large number, and I can't comprehend how to prove that an untestably large program is a proper quine. Especially in a language as painful as brain-flak.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem I can indeed demonstrate that the code works as intended and create a generative formula.  The code has a very clear and well defined pattern that makes it the size it is.

Comment: ---That... isn't a link to your answer...--- Ah, it's a link to the *question*? I would recommend removing the anchor so that it doesn't jump down below the question body when you navigate to the page.

Answer (score 10):

## If you can describe the program and show why it works, then definitely

People have done this sort of thing many times before, myself included: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58557/31343 (This one's description was much simpler than yours, but the same principle applies)

There is no reason to restrict answers to those that can be manually written out, and if you make it clear why your answer would work, then it should be completely fine.

*P.S: Awesome, a brain-flak quine!*

Comment: [Beware of bugs in the above code; I have only proved it correct, not tried it.](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth)